# A RESTful singleton resource

Tags: rest, singleton

I'm coming from the RPC world but currently investigating if using REST is a good idea for my project. As for as I understand from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_services) the basic idea of RESTful services is to provide access to collections and their individual elements.

In my case the server would be a measuring instrument. I must be able to start, stop, and pause the measurement routine, and read the data at any time.

Currently, I'm considering the following:

- **POST /measure** (start measurement, this continues until stopped by the user)
- **PUT /measure** pause=true/false (pause/unpause)
- **DELETE /measure** (stop)
- **GET /measure** (get measurement data)

However, I'm not sure if this fits the REST model, since I don't really work with collections or elements here.

My question: How would I access a singleton resource and do the start/stop requests to the server break the RESTful stateless constraint?

Comment: Belongs to http://programmers.stackexchange.com in my opinion, as it's more of a design question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are still working on a resource, and the way you broke it down sounds good to me.  Fielding explicitly mentions temporaral services in the [REST chapter](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1):

> The key abstraction of information in REST is a resource. Any
>   information that can be named can be a resource: a document or image,
>   a temporal service (e.g. "today's weather in Los Angeles")

Maybe it would make sense to give each measurement a unique id though. That way you can uniquely refer to each measurement (you don't even have to store the old ones, but if someone refers to an old measurement you can tell them, that what they are requesting is not up to date anymore).

Comment: Seems I am on the right track then. However, my application needs to control and reflect the current state of the machine (i.e. measuring, or not measuring), but that might not be a problem then.

Comment: The id might also reflect what you are measuring (e.g. weather/la). But I would say you can keep it the way you have it right now. That API is already more RESTful than many other that claim to be.

Answer (score 22):

## Not RESTful

No, your approach isn't RESTful, because if I understand the workflow, you would delete the resource to stop the measurement and then get the resource to read out the final result. But deleting a resource implies that there would be nothing left to `GET`.

The fact that your resource is a singleton isn't a problem at all. The problem lies in the way you're mapping verbs and state.

Your description is a bit abstract, so let's be a bit more concrete: let's assume that the instrument in question measures the angular velocity of a fly wheel in radians/sec. This instrument has some cost associated with measurement, so the client needs to be able to disable measurement for some periods of time as a cost-saving measure. If this is roughly analogous to your scenario, then the exposition below should be applicable to your scenario.

## Verbs

Now, let's review your verbs.

`GET` returns a representation of a resource. So when you `GET /measure`, it should return some data that represents the current measurement.

`PUT` creates or updates a specific, named resource. The resource is named by its URL. So `PUT /measure` implies that you're updating the state of a resource called `/measure`, or creating that resource if it doesn't already exist. In your case, the instrument value is read-only: we can't write a radian/sec value to the instrument. But the paused/active *state* of the instrument is mutable, so `PUT /measure` should include a body that modifies the *state* of the instrument. You could use a lot of different representations here, but one simple approach would be a request body like `active=true` or `active=false` to indicate what thew instrument's new state should be.

`POST` is similar to `PUT`, except that the client does not specify the name of the resource that should be created or updated. In a different API, for example, the client might `POST /articles` to create a new a article. The server would create a resource and give it a name like  `/articles/1234` and then it would tell the client about this new name by returning a `201 CREATED` HTTP code and adding a `Location: /articles/1234` header to tell the client where the new resource is. In your scenario, `POST` isn't a meaningful verb because you always know what the name of your singleton resource is.

`DELETE` means you remove a resource, and since a resource is identified by a URL, `DELETE /measure` implies that `/measure` no longer exists. A subsequent `GET /measure` should return either `404 NOT FOUND` or `410 GONE`. In your case, the client can't actually destroy the instrument, so `DELETE` isn't meaningful a meaningful verb.

## Conclusion

So in sum, a RESTful design for your service would be to have `PUT /measure` with a request body that tells the instrument whether it should be active or not active (paused) and `GET /measure` to read the current measurement. If you `GET /measure` on a paused instrument, you should probably return a `409 CONFLICT` HTTP status. Your service shouldn't use `POST` or `DELETE` at all.

Answer (score 1):

Building upon the last answer. Here is how you might want to break it down

- measures/ - GET all the measures from the instrument (Paginate/limit if needed based on query params)
- measures/:measure_id - GET a particular measure
- measures/ - POST - Starts a new measure. This returns the new measure ID which you can deal with later.
- measures/:measure_id - DELETE - stop the measure.
- measures/:measure_id - PUT - update the measure
- measures/last_measure - Last measured resource.

Comment: Seems how I would do it too. Unfortunately the instrument can't store any data, so a measurement id would just point to the current measurement i suppose.